# Combining get() method and %s string

Tags: python, string, get

I'm not sure if combining get() and string is my problem. I'm sure its not my only problem but here is the code. It returns an Attribute error 'str' has no attribute 'get'. Thanks.

```
for i in xrange(0, len(all_entry)):
    if len("%s".get()) == 0 % (all_entry[i]): 
        exec("%s.insert(0, \"N/A\")" % (all_entry[i])) ;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a list (all_entry) which are text boxes. I want to check if they are empty, if so, insert "N/A".

Comment: You don't need to use `exec()` here.  Please don't use `exec()` unless there absolutely, positively, 100% no other way to accomplish the task.

Comment: @user2631279 Does the list contain names of text boxes, or the text box objects themselves?  What UI toolkit are you using?

Comment: Tkinter, and im using grid for text boxes. I guess

Comment: And the list is the names of the text boxes. all_entry = ['stock','type','make','model','year']. ex. stock.grid(row=3, column=5)

Comment: @user2631279 Is there a reason you can't just store the text box objects directly in the list? Then you can very easily eliminate your `exec()`.

Comment: I'm new (ignorant). So your suggesting making my list something like all_entry = ['stock.get()','type.get()','make.get()']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59383/discussion-between-user2631279-and-cdhowie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `all_entry` contains strings that refer to text box objects.  I would strongly suggest replacing those with the actual objects themselves, if you don't depend elsewhere on them being strings.  Then, if I understand your intent correctly, your loop becomes very simple:

```
for textbox in all_entry:
    if len(textbox.get()) == 0:
        textbox.insert(0, "N/A")
```

Comment: Great help. Works just like i need it.